# how can remove the last marker google maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a html form for adding new places in my data ,

I want the user add marker and delete last marker ,

I found this code but it is added more than one marker

How can make it delete the last one?

because I need just one marker? this is the demo of form http://saudi-hotels.info/add_hotel.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var map;
function mapa()
{
    var opts = {'center': new google.maps.LatLng(26.12295, -80.17122), 
    'zoom':11, 'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapdiv'),opts);

                google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(event) {

                        document.getElementById('long').value = event.latLng.lng();
                        document.getElementById('lat').value = event.latLng.lat();

                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(event.latLng.lat(),event.latLng.lng()),
                  });

                  }


);

}
</script>
```

please help me ,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a global variable that tracks the last created marker:

```
var lastMarker;
```

And then, whenever you create a new marker, set `lastMarker` to the newly created marker:

```
lastMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(26.12295, -80.17122)
});
```

Then, whenever you want to remove the last created marker, you can use the `lastMarker` variable:

```
lastMarker.setMap(null);
```